# Cloud Server Configuration Recommendation for a Website with roughly 50,000 visitors per day

Tags: hosting, cloud, web

Background:
- Hosting a Travel related website
- Roughly 50,000 Visitors /day, distributed with usual spread across the day .
- All Static content served via RackSpace CDN
- 64 Bit Windows Environment Running SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition + Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7

Options (same cost for both):
1. Single Cloud Server for DB + Web with 8 GB of RAM - 4 Virtual CPU Cores
2. 2 4GB Servers one for DB and one for Web - 2 Virtual CPU Cores on each

Currently I have Dedicated Server with 12 GB RAM + Dual Quad Core CPU (Sounds like no brainer with this but I am considering moving to cloud because option 3 server is continuously under brute force SQL sa attack and availability is shaky.

Question:
Considering approx usage and platform what would the experts recommend is better configuration option, please note CPU cores difference between 2.

I am moving from dedicated server as that server gets millions of sa password attempts and even after getting new IP and Server it shows same attacks which decreases my confidence in provider setup. The site does not pull up 7 times out of 10.

Comment: I just found out about RackSpace sites which sounds promising especially because it comes in built with redundancy, load balancing etc. However, on the other hand it sounds like a glorified version of shared hosting. Another option. If anyone has tried it or has some input, please help decide.

Answer (score 0):

To me, your Option 1 seems good but though with a Failover option. May be you can consider putting 2 servers under a load balancer.

Regarding your reasons to move for a Cloud solution..
- Please note that SQL brute force attacks may not stop just because you move to cloud. The easiest and quick fix for this is to block the sql port from being accessed by external servers except your localhost and webserver. So suggest you block port 1433 using firewall or otherwise you are inviting trouble in my opinion.

- Also Sql injection attacks also are not likely to stop just because you moved to cloud. Your website code must be capable of preventing such attacks. Suggest you move your website to a good content management system like joomla(php), mambo (php) or dotnetnuke(asp.net) as systems like these are built with great care. And one of the basic features they provide is to prevent such injection attacks.

  I personally have done the same by moving from a custom asp .net website to dotnetnuke and have never regretted the decision.

Comment: thanks muthu. point noted about sql ports. If i lock SQL ports etc do you think the dedicated server I have (being more powerful specs) is a better choice, or should I go with the cloud?

Comment: I would preferably choose to go with cloud for reasons of image backup/restore, better geographical distribution, load balancing, scalability, high availability etc.,

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a recommendation without knowing the profile of the app e.g. how heavy is the DB load, are you using a cache infrontbof it etc.

In general with option 2 the DB will need more RAM than the webserver